# bxSlider transition between photos

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a slider that shows 4 pics at a time, so when I press next/prev it shows the other 4 pics but I'm pulling 10 pics of the db so some of them it's being cutted. Is there something I can do in js to jump one by one instead of 4?

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/npbvc4wm/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="pic1" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic2" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic3" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic4" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic5" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic6" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic7" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic8" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic9" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic10" /></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 240,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 4,
    pager: false,
    controls: true,
    auto: false,
    pause: 5000
});
```

Comment: `moveSlides: 1,` : The number of slides to move on transition. This value must be >= minSlides, and <= maxSlides. If zero (default), the number of fully-visible slides will be used.

Comment: thankss very much !